# how to install load,install the apk in karbonn tablet and how to add the file manager in karbonn tablet.?

Tags: android, android-1.6-donut

We are developing some android application.**It used android 1.6**. When we deploy the application in that application **samsung** tablet, it works. But if we try to deploy into **karbonn** tablet, we cannot deploy it.

**There is no file manager in karbonn tablet.** There is a seperate folder (for sdcard ) is displayed in applications options. It will correctly come in samsung tablet. But it does not come in karbonn tablet.

We cannot find the solution. We want to put the .apk files in karbonn tablet and installed and need to test it.

So please give your ideas how to install load, install the .apk in karbonn tablet and how to add the file manager in karbonn tablet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

send apk file to your email and open attachment in tablet, apk file will get installed

Answer (score 0):

please goto play store and install Astro manager after installed open that astro manager u will find all folders. put that apk file as your wish:)))